# How select row from html table and get the value of the first cell and put it on PHP Session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to select and get the value of selected row or to get the value of first cell of the row and restore it on PHP Session, but I don't know how to do it.

```
       <?php

       include('dbconnection.php');


                echo "<table id='tblMain' width='100%' height='10%' border='2' align='center'>
                <tr width='100%' height ='10%'>
                <th>Applicant ID</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Middlename</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Civil Status</th>
                <th>Cellphone</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>

                </tr>";

        $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_applicant");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){//this will fecth the values from database
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['ApplicantID'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['Lastname'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['Firstname'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['Middlename'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['Age'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['Gender'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['CivilStatus'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['Cellphone'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row['EmailAddress'];
                echo '</td>';

                    }
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '</table>'; 

                ?>
```

This is for my thesis.

Comment: you don't know how to select or how to "session"?

Comment: you can do `$_SESSION['ApplicantID']=$row[0]`

Comment: I tried a code with jquery, but it just selects the row, i dont know how to put that value to session??

Comment: then how can i assure that $row['ApplicantID'] is the selected first row from html? thank you sir

Comment: tell us more clearly what do you want to do

Comment: i want to click/select a row in HTML table, and get the value of clicked/selected row and store it in Session?? Sorry sir if my questions is vague, I dont know how to ask it clearly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start session, and set with $_SESSION['key']=$value_you_want_to_store

```
       include('dbconnection.php');


                echo "<table id='tblMain' width='100%' height='10%' border='2' align='center'>
                <tr width='100%' height ='10%'>
                <th>Applicant ID</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Middlename</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Civil Status</th>
                <th>Cellphone</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>

                </tr>";

        $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_applicant");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){//this will fecth the values from database
               ?><tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ApplicantID'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Lastname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Firstname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Middlename'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Age'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Gender'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['CivilStatus'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Cellphone'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['EmailAddress'];?></td>
             </tr><?php


             $_SESSION['ApplicantID']=$row['ApplicantID'];
             $_SESSION['Lastname']=$row['Lastname'];
             $_SESSION['Firstname']=$row['Firstname'];
             $_SESSION['Middlename']=$row['Middlename'];
             $_SESSION['Age']=$row['Age'];
             $_SESSION['Gender']=$row['Gender'];
             $_SESSION['CivilStatus']=$row['CivilStatus'];
             $_SESSION['Cellphone']=$row['Cellphone'];
             $_SESSION['EmailAddress']=$row['EmailAddress'];


             }


            ?> </table>
```

Comment: if you want to print your session var, you can do :
<?
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
?>

Comment: Sir you showed me how to store value to Session but still i dont know how to do it with selecting HTML table row??